# Make a terminal style TextInput in kivy?

Tags: python, user-interface, terminal, kivy, textinput

Im making an app in kivy and I was wondering if theres a way to make a TextInput box with an interface similar to Mac's 'Terminal' application. Is this possible?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/aron-bordin/8ed0d0e977e6af7a788b

Comment: Thank you, that helped alot! I just finished the app ;)

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question with a link to the code. It would be helpful for others.